# Error Handling Objective C during no response

Tags: objective-c, api, nsurlsession

In my app I use following methods to POST/GET data from a remote server.

```
     postData = [self sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    - (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
{

    NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    BOOL __block reqProcessed = false;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable _data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable _response, NSError * _Nullable _error) {
        resp = _response;
        err = _error;
        data = _data;
        reqProcessed = true;
    }] resume];

    while (!reqProcessed) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0];
    }

*response = resp;
*error = err;
return data;
```

}

I have basic error handling for no network connectivity, and app directs users to no network connectivity viewController. But I would like to account for situations when for instance server is down or data format of api has changed, Just wondering how would I catch such errors and prevent the app from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of general points:

- Don't do requests synchronously.  Pass in a block with code that should run when the request completes.  There's no reason to tie up a thread waiting for a completion handler to run, and it is even worse if that thread is basically continuously running as yours is.
- If you absolutely *must* do that (why?), at least use a semaphore and wait on the semaphore.  That way, you aren't burning a CPU core continuously while you wait.

The way you avoid crashing is to sanity check the data you get back, e.g.

- Check the length of the data and make sure you didn't get nil/empty response data.
- Assuming the server sends a JSON response, wrap your NSJSONSerialization parsing in an @try block, and if it fails or throws an exception, handle the error in some useful way.
- Generally assume that all data is invalid until proven otherwise.  Check to make sure the data makes sense.
- If you're in charge of the server side, consider passing an API version as an argument, and as you modify things in the future, make sure that incompatible changes occur only when responding to clients that request a newer API version (or, alternatively, send a response that tells the client that it needs to be upgraded, and then refuse to provide data).

Comment: NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    BOOL __block reqProcessed = false;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable _data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable _response, NSError * _Nullable _error) {
        resp = _response;
        err = _error;
        data = _data;
        
    }]  Using it like that shouldn't tie the thread ?

Comment: What's tying up a thread is the while loop that repeatedly sleeps for zero time and then checks the value.

Comment: Ok got it, for NSJSONSerialization, I could pass NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];  , if the the data is nil I could avoid running the code. As it would pass nil as dict object? or you think @try block is better approach ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't recall what NSJSONSerialization does when it gets corrupted or truncated data; it might throw then, too.  If so, an \@try block would catch that case, whereas a nil check won't.  I tend to favor \@try, but it's entirely up to you.